# C++ make folder inside Program files

Tags: c++, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory inside program files, but my code failed. I can make folder directly on the root, so this is very strange I think.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

#include <direct.h> // _mkdir

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Make directory
    if(_mkdir("C:\\Program Files\\MyProgram") == 0 ){
        cout << "Folder created" << endl; 
    }
    else{
         cout << "Folder creation failed" << endl; 
    }


    // Pause program
    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
Thank you. I understand that c:\Program files\MyProgram is only for install files, but where should I put save files? Example save files for a C++ game. Should they be stored in "C:\Users\Username\Documents\MyProgram"?

Comment: Do you have administrative privileges? If not, anything past Windows Vista will not allow you to do so.

Comment: Rightclick your exe -> run program as admin

Comment: @Cyber: XP can block access to Program Files as well.

Comment: @Solo, when `_mkdir()` fails, use [`errno`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx) to find out why it failed. You are likely getting an `EPERM` (Operation not permitted) or `EACCES` (Permission denied) error.

Comment: Generally, you should *not* be writing anything to system directories. If this is for an install of a program, use a proper installer technology which will handle things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper folder name to write depends on version and localization.

A  simple way to get that name is to search for the `APPDATA` environment variable.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188(v=vs.85).aspx) to get an environment variable, and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744(v=ws.10).aspx) about the recognized environment variables and meanings.